# Replaced InnerHtml Displays as a String

Tags: c#, html, innerhtml, visual-web-developer

I must be missing the obvious here.  I have a drop down menu in a table cell that selects an image to display in that cell after which the drop down menu disappears.  I am able to do this with text values in the drop down list by replacing the inner html that holds the drop down list.  But when I try to replace the inner html with the location of the image file it just displays as text.  Here is the relevant code:

```
string image = "&ltimg src=&quot;" + DropList1.SelectedItem.Value + "&quot; /&gt";
s1.InnerHtml = image;
```

and the output is:

```
<img src="D:\Documents and Settings\farmek2\Desktop\Trends\GreenUp.jpeg" />
```

I need this not to display as text but rather as the image GreenUp.jpg.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Million answers GO! [jQuery Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the actual markup, not the encoded string.

```
string image = "<img src=\"" + DropList1.SelectedItem.Value + "\" />";
```

Comment: Thanks.  That gets rid of the text (I was certain I had tried this already).  Now the problem is that the image doesn't display.

Comment: That's because you are using the local hard drive reference, not a URL accessible by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is more thank likely because you are injecting HTML special characters into an HTML page. Rather than being rendered as HTML, a browser converts it in the corresponding symbol. Use the actual characters and not their special character equivalents.